# How to solve JBoss Remote error?

Tags: java, junit, jboss, compiler-errors

I'm trying to run JBoss remote in JUnit and I'm getting an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Here is part of JUnit class with Remote:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.SessionManager;

public class Test1 {

    private static SessionManager _service;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void doSms() throws Exception {
        String JBOSS_CONTEXT = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JBOSS_CONTEXT);
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpassword");
        _service = (SessionManager) new InitialContext(properties).lookup("java:global/SessionManager");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error not belongs to **JBoss Remote in JUnit**.

Check all required jar placed in your class path.

Avoid conflicting between same jar with two versions(Don't add two different version jar).

Comment: I've deleted double jars (/w different versions), and nothing changes.